# replace rand() with openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()

Tags: php, random, cryptography

I need a replacement for PHP's `rand()` function that uses a cryptographically strong random number generator.

The `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` function gets you access to the strong random number generator, but it outputs its data as a byte string. Instead, I need an integer between 0 and *X*.

I imagine the key is to get the output of `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` into an integer, then you can do any math on it that you need to. I can think of a few "brute force" ways of converting from a byte string to an integer, but I was hoping for something ... elegant.

Comment: mt_rand() will give much better quality random numbers than rand(), but it's not cryptographically strong either.

Comment: careful, this answer is wrong. to be more specific, the " % $range" part is incorrect. Take the following scenario: you want to generate numbers between 1 (including) and 4 (excluding) (since you do max-min). $range = 3. Now 3 doesn't divide evenly into 2^8 meaning that 1 is going to be more common than 3. Be very careful, you wanted to make a secure random number generator but inadvertently made it insecure, this is why it is recommended to use existing implementations.

Comment: @chacham15: If understand correctly, in an 8 bit range you get 85 sets of [1,2,3] plus a single [1,] left over, making a "1" about 1.17% more likely to turn up than "2" or "3", right? How would you solve this problem? Obviously using an *existing implementation* isn't an option, or I wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: `$num = hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length,$s)));
$max = pow(2, 8*length); //for clarity, you can replace with a faster bit shift
$remainder = $max % $range;
$max = $max - $remainder;
if ($num > $max){
 return crypto_rand($min,$max);
}
return $min + ($num % $range);`

Comment: In words, you essentially get the highest number that evenly divides into your range (which is also in the range of the random number generator) and if the value is above that you have to rerun the function.

Comment: I think you should change: $max = $max - $remainder; to $max = $max - $remainder - 1; - otherwise you get unequal distribution biased towards the first value in the range.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using provided suggestions, I've created a drop-in replacement for rand() using OpenSSL. I'll include it here for posterity.

The *$pedantic* option gives bias-free results by starting over when results won't be evenly distributed across the possible range.

```
function crypto_rand($min,$max,$pedantic=True) {
    $diff = $max - $min;
    if ($diff <= 0) return $min; // not so random...
    $range = $diff + 1; // because $max is inclusive
    $bits = ceil(log(($range),2));
    $bytes = ceil($bits/8.0);
    $bits_max = 1 << $bits;
    // e.g. if $range = 3000 (bin: 101110111000)
    //  +--------+--------+
    //  |....1011|10111000|
    //  +--------+--------+
    //  bits=12, bytes=2, bits_max=2^12=4096
    $num = 0;
    do {
        $num = hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($bytes))) % $bits_max;
        if ($num >= $range) {
            if ($pedantic) continue; // start over instead of accepting bias
            // else
            $num = $num % $range;  // to hell with security
        }
        break;
    } while (True);  // because goto attracts velociraptors
    return $num + $min;
}
```

Comment: I have added an answer with a guide on how you can use CryptoLib in order to do this as a drop in replacement. This is far safer (and has more efficient code) and it provides a repeatability checker too.

Comment: @mjsa While I'm sure your crypto library is great, this question was about the mechanics of the code itself, rather than a request for someone to build another library to do it.

Comment: This isn't a bad solution. I'm helping backport PHP 7's `random_int()` into PHP 5 projects, and our approach works even when `$max - $min > PHP_INT_MAX`. You can find our efforts on Github under [random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat) if you would like to weigh in with your own perspective.

Answer (score 8):

The manual page for `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` has an example I think you want. You can just call `bin2hex()` on the output of `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` to convert to a hexadecimal number, then `hexdec()` on that value to convert to decimal.

```
$rand_num = hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length, $strong)));
```

At that point you can do whatever math you want to get a value in the range you need. The other (cheater) option you might have is to run a system command to generate a random number - there are a few good options for random number generators for various operating systems available online.

Comment: This doesn't fully answer the question, see the other answers below.

Answer (score 2):

Heres a version of the solutions above, which doesn't use recursive function calls:

```
function secure_rand($min,$max) {
    $range = $max - $min + 1;
    if ($range == 0) return $min;
    $length = (int) (log($range,2) / 8) + 1;
    $max = pow(2, 8 * $length);
    $num = $max + 1; // Hackish, I know..
    while ($num > $max) {
        $num = hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length,$s)));
    }
    return ($num  % $range) + $min;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since PHP 7 is out now, the easiest way to solve this problem is to replace all instances of `mt_rand` with [`random_int`](https://secure.php.net/random_int).

(Assuming you've upgraded, that is.)

Answer (score 1):

well, just use hexdec on the result of openssl_random_pseudo_bytes and you will get your integer. It is as elegant as it gets :)

```
print hexdec('45261b8f');

>  1160125327
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the ops question since rand takes a min and max and this just returns a random number.

Comment: Not directly, but it is fairly trivial to add this - as you can see from the solution provided by the op himself.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this (and the most secure out of all the options here) is to use CryptoLib which has a randomInt function that provides a drop-in replacement for rand.

First download CryptoLib from and stick it in your project: https://github.com/IcyApril/CryptoLib

Two, drop in this code. replace path/to/ with the directory of cryptolib.php and the min max with your minimum and maximum numbers:

```
<?php
  require_once('path/to/cryptoLib.php');

  $min = 1;
  $max = 5;

  $randomNum = CryptoLib::randomInt($min, $max);
?>
```

The CryptoLib full documentation is at: https://cryptolib.ju.je/

Answer (score -1):

```
function ($min,$max){
    $range = $max-$min+1;
    do{
        $result = floor($range*(hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(4)))/0xffffffff));
    } while($result == $range);    
    return $result + $min;
}
```