# How to create and use nonces

Tags: php, actionscript-3, cryptography, nonce

I am running a website, and there is a scoring system that gives you points for the number of times you play a game.

It uses hashing to prove the integrity of http request for scoring so users cannot change anything, however as I feared might happen, someone figured out that they didn't need to change it, they just needed to get a high score, and duplicate the http request, headers and all.

Previously I'd been prohibited from protecting against this attack because it was considered unlikely. However, now that it has happened, I can. The http request originates from a flash game, and then is validated by php and php enters it into the database.

I'm pretty sure nonces will solve the issue, but I'm not exactly sure how to implement them. What is a common, and secure way of setting up a nonce system?

Comment: Be aware that anything a flash game does on your client can be replicated by someone with a decompiler/packet-sniffer and enough time.  So any protection you add can be defeated.

Comment: It's the amount of time invested to falsely mainpulate in that I'm interested in increasing. Yes, they can decompile it and replace it, but the hashing algorithm isn't a secret and only protects because it has a secret salt, which if they're smart, they can figure out with a rainbow table.

Comment: This is why the ban hammer was invented.

Comment: @cdhowie - Not really, you can record a play of a gameplay and then replay it on server, and then take the score gained from the replay, to put things short. Coding horror though ;).

Comment: Maurycy: That would not prevent against replaying the same game over and over.  Nor would it prevent people from implementing their own game record generator.

Comment: What values do you have at your disposal to create the nonce with? Is there a login system? Can you explain the scoring a little better?

Comment: There is a login system. Game scores are recorded to a user. Users' also have another scoring system which is how active they are on the site. They get one point for each time they play a game (or more if it's a high score), so what is happening is that the user is artificially inflating their "site activity" score.

Comment: @cdhowie: You can protect against replaying by rejecting any perfect-replica games, on the reasonable assumption that a real player would introduce tiny timing differences from game to game.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It's actually quite easy to do...  There are some libraries out there to do it for you:

1. [PHP Nonce Library](http://fullthrottledevelopment.com/php-nonce-library)
2. [OpenID Nonce Library](http://shupp.org/openiddoc/__filesource/fsource_OpenID__OpenIDNonce.php.html)

Or if you want to write your own, it's pretty simple.  Using the [WikiPedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) as a jumping off point, In pseudo-code:

On the server side, you need two client callable functions

```
getNonce() {
    $id = Identify Request //(either by username, session, or something)
    $nonce = hash('sha512', makeRandomString());
    storeNonce($id, $nonce);
    return $nonce to client;
}

verifyNonce($data, $cnonce, $hash) {
    $id = Identify Request
    $nonce = getNonce($id);  // Fetch the nonce from the last request
    removeNonce($id, $nonce); //Remove the nonce from being used again!
    $testHash = hash('sha512',$nonce . $cnonce . $data);
    return $testHash == $hash;
}
```

And on the client side:

```
sendData($data) {
    $nonce = getNonceFromServer();
    $cnonce = hash('sha512', makeRandomString());
    $hash = hash('sha512', $nonce . $cnonce . $data);
    $args = array('data' => $data, 'cnonce' => $cnonce, 'hash' => $hash);
    sendDataToClient($args);
}
```

The function `makeRandomString` really just needs to return a random number or string.  The better the randomness, the better the security...  Also note that since it's fed right into a hash function, the implementation details don't matter from request to request.  The client's version and the server's version don't need to match.  In fact, the only bit that needs to match 100% is the hash function used in `hash('sha512', $nonce . $cnonce . $data);`...  Here's an example of a reasonably secure `makeRandomString` function...

```
function makeRandomString($bits = 256) {
    $bytes = ceil($bits / 8);
    $return = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $bytes; $i++) {
        $return .= chr(mt_rand(0, 255));
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Good answer but generating a nonce then transmitting via http (i.e open wire) doesn't prevent against replay attacks. Age old problem of 'can you trust the client' and the answer is invariably 'no'. Unless you have server side session logic then this is hard.

Comment: @zebrabox, Nonces would protect against replay attacks. Nonces are "numbers only used once" so you just maintain a listing of the nonces used previously, and deny any attempt to use a nonce twice.

Comment: Downvoted because the linked library, FT-Nonce, is extremely insecure in it's generation of unique keys.

Comment: What's logic of creating `$id` ? If we use session, need to pass session id to client and client send session id back to server to recognize what nonce is being used?

Answer (score 37):

### Nonces are a can of worms.

No, really, one of the motivations for several [CAESAR](https://competitions.cr.yp.to/caesar.html) entries was to design an authenticated encryption scheme, preferably based on a stream cipher, that is resistant to nonce reuse. (Reusing a nonce with AES-CTR, for example, destroys the confidentiality of your message to the degree a first year programming student could decrypt it.)

There are three main schools of thought with nonces:

1. In symmetric-key cryptography: Use an increasing counter, while taking care to never reuse it. (This also means using a separate counter for the sender and receiver.) This requires stateful programming (i.e. storing the nonce somewhere so each request doesn't start at `1`).
2. Stateful random nonces. Generating a random nonce and then remembering it to validate later. **This is the strategy used to defeat CSRF attacks,** which sounds closer to what is being asked for here.
3. Large stateless random nonces. Given a secure random number generator, you can almost guarantee to never repeat a nonce twice in your lifetime. This is the strategy used by [NaCl](https://competitions.cr.yp.to/caesar.html) for encryption.

So with that in mind, the main questions to ask are:

1. Which of the above schools of thought are most relevant to the problem you are trying to solve?
2. How are you generating the nonce?
3. How are you validating the nonce?

### Generating a Nonce

The answer to question 2 for any random nonce is to use a CSPRNG. For PHP projects, this means one of:

- [`random_bytes()`](https://secure.php.net/random_bytes) for PHP 7+ projects
- [paragonie/random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat), a PHP 5 polyfill for `random_bytes()`
- [ircmaxell/RandomLib](https://github.com/ircmaxell/RandomLib), which is a swiss army knife of randomness utilities that most projects that deal with randomness (e.g. fir password resets) should consider using instead of rolling their own

These two are morally equivalent:

```
$factory = new RandomLib\Factory;
$generator = $factory->getMediumStrengthGenerator();
$_SESSION['nonce'] [] = $generator->generate(32);
```

and

```
$_SESSION['nonce'] []= random_bytes(32);
```

### Validating a Nonce

#### Stateful

Stateful nonces are easy and recommended:

```
$found = array_search($nonce, $_SESSION['nonces']);
if (!$found) {
    throw new Exception("Nonce not found! Handle this or the app crashes");
}
// Yay, now delete it.
unset($_SESSION['nonce'][$found]);
```

Feel free to substitute the `array_search()` with a database or memcached lookup, etc.

#### Stateless (here be dragons)

This is a hard problem to solve: You need some way to prevent replay attacks, but your server has total amnesia after each HTTP request.

The only sane solution would be to authenticate an expiration date/time to minimize the usefulness of replay attacks. For example:

```
// Generating a message bearing a nonce
$nonce = random_bytes(32);
$expires = new DateTime('now')
    ->add(new DateInterval('PT01H'));
$message = json_encode([
    'nonce' => base64_encode($nonce),
    'expires' => $expires->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s')
]);
$publishThis = base64_encode(
    hash_hmac('sha256', $message, $authenticationKey, true) . $message
);

// Validating a message and retrieving the nonce
$decoded = base64_decode($input);
if ($decoded === false) {
    throw new Exception("Encoding error");
}
$mac = mb_substr($decoded, 0, 32, '8bit'); // stored
$message = mb_substr($decoded, 32, null, '8bit');
$calc = hash_hmac('sha256', $message, $authenticationKey, true); // calcuated
if (!hash_equals($calc, $mac)) {
    throw new Exception("Invalid MAC");
}
$message = json_decode($message);
$currTime = new DateTime('NOW');
$expireTime = new DateTime($message->expires);
if ($currTime > $expireTime) {
    throw new Exception("Expired token");
}
$nonce = $message->nonce; // Valid (for one hour)
```

A careful observer will note that this is basically a non-standards-compliant variant of [JSON Web Tokens](https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt).

Comment: Can't you prevent replay attacks by writing the nonce to the database, and when it's "redeemed" you delete it from the database?  So take your "Stateful" method, and replace $_SESSION['nonces'] with a nonces table that links the nonce to a username (and perhaps a timeout)?

Comment: That's what we've done but with an expiration column so we can limit the lifespan and clear out abandoned SSO attempts.

Answer (score 2):

One option (which I mentioned in comment) is recording gameplay and replay it in secure environment.

The other thing is to randomly, or at some specified times, record some seemingly innocent data, which later can be used to validate it on server (like suddenly live goes from 1% to 100%, or score from 1 to 1000 which indicate cheat). With enough data it might just not be feasible for cheater to try to fake it. And then of course implement heavy banning :).

Answer (score 2):

This very simple nonce changes every 1000 seconds (16 minutes)
and can be used for avoiding XSS where you are posting data to and from the same application. (For example if you are in a single page application where you are posting data via javascript. Note that you must have access to the same seed and nonce generator from the post and the receiving side)

```
function makeNonce($seed,$i=0){
    $timestamp = time();
    $q=-3; 
    //The epoch time stamp is truncated by $q chars, 
    //making the algorthim to change evry 1000 seconds
    //using q=-4; will give 10000 seconds= 2 hours 46 minutes usable time

    $TimeReduced=substr($timestamp,0,$q)-$i; 

    //the $seed is a constant string added to the string before hashing.    
    $string=$seed.$TimeReduced;
    $hash=hash('sha1', $string, false);
    return  $hash;
}
```

But by checking for the previous nonce, the user will only be bothered if he waited more than 16.6 minutes in worst case and 33 minutes in best case. Setting $q=-4 will give the user at least 2.7 hours

```
function checkNonce($nonce,$seed){
//Note that the previous nonce is also checked giving  between 
// useful interval $t: 1*$qInterval < $t < 2* $qInterval where qInterval is the time deterimined by $q: 
//$q=-2: 100 seconds, $q=-3 1000 seconds, $q=-4 10000 seconds, etc.
    if($nonce==$this->makeNonce($seed,0)||$nonce==$this->makeNonce($seed,1))     {
         //handle data here
         return true;
     } else {
         //reject nonce code   
         return false;
     }
}
```

The $seed, could be the any function  call or user name, etc. used in the process.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to prevent cheating. You can only make it more difficult.

If someone came here looking for a PHP Nonce Library: I recommend not using [the first one given by ircmaxwell](http://fullthrottledevelopment.com/php-nonce-library).

The first comment on the website describes a design flaw:

> The nonce is good for one certain time window, i.e. the nearer the
>   user gets to the end of that windows the less time he or she has to
>   submit the form, possibly less than one second

If you are looking for a way to generate Nonces with a well-defined lifetime, have a look at [NonceUtil-PHP](https://github.com/timostamm/NonceUtil-PHP).

Disclaimer: I am the author of NonceUtil-PHP

Comment: Can you confirm that this utility, authored more than a year ago, is still a good choice?

Comment: @NathanArthur if you check the author, it's Timo himself. His NonceUtil.php uses sha-1, does not check previous nonces and has an hardcoded string for salt... The 1st library listed in ircmaxwell's answer uses md5 and the 2nd one uses a simple rand to create the nonce. I.e. none uses sha256/sha512. However, if the goal of the nonce is just to have a non-repeatable string, then you just need a good random generator (e.g.: [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313223)) and then to store the generated ones in order to check before using them.

Comment: I would not recommend NonceUtil as currently implemented.