# php session validation

Tags: php, validation, session

I want to achieve that a user cannot send the same input twice. I use a php script to submit user input.

My idea is to save his inputs in a session array and each time that he submits something check through the array if it matches one of the things he already submitted before.

The code looks like this:

```
    //Compare post with what user has posted so far; if the same, exit (spam protection)
    foreach($_SESSION['postarray'][] as $postarray) if($post=$postarray) exit;

    //Save post in session of all other posts
    $_SESSION['postarray'][]=$post;
```

I get the following error:

Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/postish/action/post.php on line 32 (which refers to the line with the foreach() loop)

Even after changing the function to only $_SESSION['post array'], it doesn't work either.

Any help much appreciated :)

Dennis

Comment: the error message suggests that the `"[]" syntax` is wrong. Try removing the empty brackets. And `=` is for assignments. `==` is for conditions.

Comment: Premise is fundamentally flawed as is method of implementation. How do you deal with an ever-growing session? Why not at the storage tier? I suspect you really want to prevent the user submitting the same instance of a form multiple times - in which case this should be managed at the client. See also CSRF prevention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operator `[]` adds a new element to array.

To get elements for foreach loop you have to use it without `[]`:

```
foreach($_SESSION['postarray'] as $postarray)
    if ($post == $postarray) exit;
```

And pay attention to comparison operator `==` which is used to check the equality of the variables.

The better option to check if `$post` exists in `$_SESSION['postarray']` is to use [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function:

```
if (in_array($post, $_SESSION['postarray'])) exit;
```

Answer (score 2):

You accidentally used the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparion operator `==` or `===`.

So you need to replace `if($post=$postarray)` with `if($post == $postarray)`

You also need to remove the `[]` in `foreach($_SESSION['postarray'][] as $postarray)` as `[]` is only used when inserting a new array element.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop a user from sending the same data twice, you need to look into using a `nonce` (number used once)

There are a few examples:

- [How to create and use nonces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145531/how-to-create-and-use-nonces)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce
- http://fullthrottledevelopment.com/php-nonce-library