# Do not submit same data twice php

Tags: php

How would I check in PHP if the exact same data has not been already sent?

This will prohibit users (accidently) sending a contact form twice with the same data on my website!.

Thanks!

Comment: You are probably saving that data in a database? Before inserting, check if it already exists?

Comment: Are you storing the information being submitted into a database before or after sending the mail.?

Comment: You need something called "nonce". Refer this SO thread for further info about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145531/how-to-create-and-use-nonces

Comment: Small fragment revise

Comment: if someone has the history, can check last mail send from user and match it! that does it, you know whether to send it again or not :)

Comment: This question doesn't have anything to do with PHPMailer so I'm removing the tag.

Comment: it is not saved in a database, it is a contact form which sends an email

Answer (score 1):

You can for example serialize the form data and store it in a session variable. Upon receiving form data, first check if the same data is already present in the session.
You can also add a random number to the form as hidden input field which is also stored in $_SESSION["rand"]. Upon the first submit, the random number is checked for equality and then removed (or changed) in the session array. This way, a single form can only be used once, upon a second submit, the number will be different and not accepted anymore.

When generating a form:

```
$_SESSION["rand"] = rand();
```

And add in the form:

```
<input type='hidden' name='rand' value='{$_SESSION["rand"]}' />
```

Upon receiving, check:

```
if ( $_SESSION["rand"] === $_POST["rand"]) {
    $_SESSION["rand"] = false;
    // continue with stuff...
```

Of course, with this layout, a single user can only open a single form at the same time, since opening a second form will overwrite the random number.
An even better approach would be to create a individual session key and value combination for each form, thus two forms will not overwrite each other.