# Create Unique ID for URL

Tags: php, loops, unique

I am working on pages which are secured so no-one can link to that page using this:

Code below is called inside a loop.

```
$gentok = uniqid();

if(isset($_GET["action"]) && $_GET["action"] == "clean_$gentok") {
    // stuff
}
```

Then, I have this to call the URL:

```
<a href="<?php echo admin_url("themes.php?page=cleaner&action=clean_$gentok"); ?>">Clean this and that</a>
```

But when clicking the link, the page refreshes and the `uniqid()` has already changed.

How can I make it so the `uniqid()` is still the same after the page refresh? I'm open for any changes or better ideas you may have.

Thank you!

Comment: Save unique ID in session along with a timestamp and then renew the ID after some time (and/or when the link has been clicked).

Comment: I'm curious; is this to be used for one-time only use? If so, there's a better way.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes one time only

Comment: I had a feeling about that. Why not use a nonce?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I thought uniqid would do the job, turns out to be a bummer... aaaand I'm not too sure how nonces work.

Comment: Have a look at this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145531/how-to-create-and-use-nonces - It's all in there ;-) I've used it often before.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ay! That works. Your link is fine but I've used the WordPress nonce system for it. Thank you for the information, Fred.

Comment: You're quite welcome, *cheers* glad it worked. TBH, I didn't know WordPress had one too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as a community wiki since I've nothing to gain from this.

My suggestion in comments about using a nonce brought the OP to use the WordPress version of a nonce as their solution.

Reference:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces

Sidenote: To be honest, I was not aware that WordPress had one and found that reference link on the Internet.

My original reference:

- [How to create and use nonces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145531/how-to-create-and-use-nonces)

Additional reference:

- Wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce

Answer (score 0):

Use session for this. Put your unique ID in session array

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['gentok'] = uniqid();

if (isset($_GET["action"]) && $_GET["action"] == "clean_" . $_SESSION['gentok']) {
    // stuff
}
```

In your display

```
session_start();

<a href="<?= admin_url('themes.php?page=cleaner&action=clean_' . $_SESSION['gentok']) ?>">Clean this and that</a>
```

Comment: Okay, thank you for the answer. Will this also work in `foreach`?

Comment: Not too crazy, just `foreach ($theme_names as $theme_name) {` and inside that the code in the question

Comment: I have found that a nonce system is kind of better for this, I might have not explained it that well in my question. Thank you anyway for your help and effort. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you creating a session set a value   so every time that  page loads it will check is your session for the value.  Else you will redirect......you would put the code on top.    `If($_SESSION['sesname']!=$value]{header location}`

You would pit this at the top of the page so it performs the check

**OR**
If you want a unique name then just put something that people want easily guess and don't link it any where