# PHP's openssl_random_pseudo_bytes Alternative for Golang?

Tags: php, go

Is there a function for Golang which is or nearly is identicle to PHP's [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) function?

I need this to generate pseudo-random string of bytes in Golang.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and lightweight pseudo-random string of bytes generator

At first define array of bytes that we want to use for our generator( in this case it shall be letters)
Then decide how many bits represent one letter(it will allow us take letters one by one) and letter "template" that contains amount of bits for one letter
Also I stored maximum index that I can take from my array of bytes

```
const (
    letterBytes   = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    letterIdxBits = 6                    // 6 bits to represent a letter index
    letterIdxMask = 1<<letterIdxBits - 1 // All 1-bits, as many as letterIdxBits
    letterIdxMax  = 63 / letterIdxBits   // # of letter indices fitting in 63 bits
)
```

StringRandomizer function gets an argument(length of string that I want to get as result)

Basically, this function just a simple loop that creates a new array of bytes with defined length, and pseudo-random elements.
Until I did not fill in all required elements of result array(did not put 'n' elements), I get one random letter from my letterBytes const.
If length of the string that I want to get at the end more that letterIdxMax, I just create new random  sequence of 63 bytes(src.Int63()) and proceed looping

```
func StringRandomizer(n int) string {
    src := rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())
    b := make([]byte, n)
    // A src.Int63() generates 63 random bits, enough for letterIdxMax characters!
    for i, cache, remain := n-1, src.Int63(), letterIdxMax; i >= 0; remain-- {
        if remain == 0 {
            cache, remain = src.Int63(), letterIdxMax
        }
        if idx := int(cache & letterIdxMask); idx < len(letterBytes) {
            b[i] = letterBytes[idx]
            i--
        }
        cache >>= letterIdxBits

    }
    return string(b)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at package "crypto/rand", [replace rand() with openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313223/replace-rand-with-openssl-random-pseudo-bytes?rq=1) and https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/blob/master/hmac_example_test.go

```
func init() {
    // Load sample key data
    if keyData, e := ioutil.ReadFile("test/hmacTestKey"); e == nil {
        hmacSampleSecret = keyData
    } else {
        panic(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: https://godoc.org/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go#example-New--Hmac I have had this issue for the whole day. I am trying to use the exact code in the link, but what do I use for the hmacSampleSecret? It's been puzzling me for so long.