# Using openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() to seed mt_rand()

Tags: php, cryptography, password-generator

I'm trying to build a simple password generating function using `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` and want to know if it is cryptographically strong.

```php
function randomPassword($length = 12) {
    mt_srand( hexdec( bin2hex( openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(256) ) ) );
    $alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$&*-_=+.?';
    $pass = '';
    $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $n = mt_rand(0, $alphaLength);
       $pass .= $alphabet[$n];
   }
   return $pass;
}
```

I would assume that if there is a weakness that is is till in the `mt_rand` function regardless of seeding it with `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`. However, I have been unable to find any discussion on the topic.

Comment: it's only as safe as it is stored. At best, I'd only use that to generate a (one time) verification token and not use it to store passwords with, should that be the case.

Comment: Right, this just for a random password to give users.
Storage is a different creature altogether (hashing and such).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php)
`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` is not guaranteed to produce cryptographically strong random data. However, in the improbable case that it was not able to use a cryptographically strong RNG, it will at least tell you. That's what `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`'s second parameter is for:

> It also indicates if a cryptographically strong algorithm was used to produce the pseudo-random bytes, and does this via the optional `crypto_strong` parameter. It's rare for this to be `FALSE`, but some systems may be broken or old.

You can pass this parameter and then check its value:

```
$bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(256, $strong);
if (!$strong) {
    // handle error as necessary.
}
```

However, opposed to `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`, `mt_rand` is [explicitly stated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) to not produce cryptographically secure values.

> This function does not generate cryptographically secure values, and should not be used for cryptographic purposes.

I'm no expert, but I doubt that seeding a Mersenne Twister with secure random data would make the generated data any more secure (if at all, probably just the first byte):

#### Counter-suggestion

You did not state which version of PHP you're using. If you are using PHP 7, [`random_int`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php) might make a good alternative for you (it's also explicitly stated to be cryptographically secure):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $n = random_int(0, $alphaLength);
    $pass .= $alphabet[$n];
}
```

Alternatively, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23624975/1995300) provides a secure, PHP-based implementation for a `rand` function that uses OpenSSL as an CSPRNG that you could use in place of `random_int`.

Comment: Thanks @helmbert.

I could include the `cryto_strong` check in the function.
Your comment about the Mersenne Twister is really at the heart of my question. I figured that `mt_rand` would be the weak point but I don't know the science behind it.

I'll check out `random_int`.

I did read that answer before asking this question. I wrote a variation of the function using some ideas from it. Thanks for linking for future readers.